# How to publish different solutions (and repositories) to the same project?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, publish, repo

I have an Azure DevOps project that contains a solution that is published to an URL like `custom.mycompany.com`. Is it possible to publish another solution in a different repository to `otherapp.custom.mycompany.com`?

If so, how could I do this?

Comment: Q: Can you publish different solutions to different Git repos owned by different company URLs?  A: Sure.  You can, of course, publish different solutions to different repos owned by the same company.  You CAN'T publish the SAME project (on your local hard disk) to DIFFERENT repos (at the same time).  Q: how could I do this?  A: Exactly the same as you'd publish any repo.  For example: https://github.com/github/VisualStudio/blob/master/docs/using/publishing-an-existing-project-to-github.md

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new git repository (as many as you want per project) using this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/create-new-repo?view=azure-devops

The question is why? Only one project into your solution is a web project.

You can use the same solution for multiple projects and websites mapping to alternate domains.

You can also create multiple folders/solutions into the same repository.

The repository organisation is a complex design. There are monorepo trends and multi repo trends. You can check pros and cons on various resources around the web.

Comment: Currently, we are using multiple web projects in the same solution. We are willing to separate that into different solutions to fulfill project designs from our customers.

Comment: How will you handle common dependencies? Nuget or some other type of packages?

Answer (score 0):

I just find out how to do this.

You can create several App Services in a single App Service Plan.
Then, it is possible to create repos and connect those repos with each App Service you have in an App Service Plan.

Then you have a lot of apps inside the same project.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).